# Window Installer custom action fails for non-Admins

Tags: setup-project, custom-action

I have a windows setup project along with my project(WPF application) where I am adding a 3rd party USB driver(Silicon Labs USBXpressInstaller.exe) as a Custom Action in the setup project which makes my .MSI file along with the USB driver.

Project Tree: MyProject and SetUp Project

Custom Action for my SetUp Project:
[image]

After I build the project and the setup project, it is installing fine if the user is an Admin but gives the error pop-up "There is a problem with this windows installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor"(see below image) every time non-Admin tries to install the MSI. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Thanks,
Sudheer

***Edits:*** Below are the properties of my Setup project

[image]

Below are the properties of the Custom Action

[image]

***Edits (08/06/2021):*** How can I suppress the below window when a non-admin is installing the msi?

[image]

**Latest Update:** I received a call from a client saying that they are not able to install the application at all. The user has DOMAIN ADMINISTRATOR rights for the PC he is trying to install on. For me, it is working now once I enter the Admin password (which I want to suppress). But, for the DOMAIN ADMINISTRATOR, there is no UAC pop-up shown as they are in the ADMINISTRATOR group but does not install as well.

Comment: Does the driver install put up a UAC prompt when you run it by itself?  If yes, you might need to update your own install to require admin rights

Comment: Also, I am trying to install it per Machine

Comment: @Dave S, thank you for responding. Yes, it does show UAC prompt. What should I update to make it work?

Comment: Dave, I added my current properties of the setup project and the custom action (as edits) to my question above. Let me know if you need anything that might help you in responding.

Comment: What are you building the MSI with?  InstallShield has a toggle for whether admin rights are required, which "sets bit 3 in the Word Count Summary property"

Comment: I am using Windows Setup Project to create the MSI file. I added my project output to the setup project and trying to add a third party (.exe)  as a custom action which is failing to install for Users with domain administrator rights. I might have explained this much better. I hardly ask questions here, so hope you understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your question is clear enough, I just read "a windows setup project" as "a windows setup" which could also mean the MSI was built by tools like InstallShield, Inno Setup, WiX Toolset, etc.  -- we use InstallShield at work so that's the one I'm familiar with.

Comment: Does this work? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5c47ca7-ebce-44ed-ae10-f3d0928521bc/installing-an-msi-in-admin-mode?forum=winformssetup   or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248667/how-do-i-force-a-visual-studio-setup-project-generated-msi-installer-to-only-run

Comment: Thank you very much, Dave. Now I am (non-Admin) able to install the application after entering the Admin credentials. How can I suppress this window?

Also, I updated the above request. Please see Edits (08/06/2021) and Latest Update for the issues I am having currently. 

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: I tried adding Manifest file to my project and I tried all the three requestedExecutionLevels and none worked. All the three are showing the UAC pop-up which I want to supress

Comment: You need admin rights to install a driver that requires admin rights, there is no way around that.  As long as you include that driver the people installing it are going to get a UAC prompt or admin password request, or an error if you fail to ask for rights.

Comment: Ok, thank you for all the help

Comment: Actually there can be one way around it, but only for some cases:  At a school or company where all of the devices have a remote management software service installed, an administrator can use that service to push out installations to the devices using it.  Admin rights are still needed, but the service that's already running has those rights.

Comment: Also, for the installer I am trying to install (Silicon Labs UBXpress) there is a .ini file which I tried to manipulate to make it work. I tried doing a silent installation since it suppresses all the pop-up windows, but when I do that I see a failed message for DOMAIN ADMINS.

The below link should have the similar .ini file in page 8

https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN335.pdf